# Are Logarithmic primes and Root primes useless?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, logarithms, radicals

I just thought about these two:

Logarithmic primes: Any natural number $n$ such that for any other natural number $a$ not equal to $n$, $\log_an$ is not an integer. That should be our logarithmic primes.

Root primes: Any natural number $n$ such that for any other natural number $a$ not equal to 1, $n^{\frac{1}{a}}$ is not an integer. That should be root primes.

I searched on the internet to see if the terms already existed but I didn't find them. So, do these terms exist? And why doesn't anyone talk about them? If they exist, they aren't popular. Are these sequences of numbers useless?

Comment: According to your definition, root primes are just the numbers not being a perfect power (If we exclude $1$)

Comment: If I do not miss something, the logarithmic primes (If we assume numbers greatert than $1$) are also the numbers, not being a perfect power.

Comment: @Peter So what? Normal primes are just numbers which are not .perfect multiples. Does that make their pattern obvious?

Comment: If I am right, the name "perfect power" covers both types of primes. In this case, there would be a name for your primes, namely "non-powers". Whether they have an "obvious" pattern, is something different.